# How to get Webdriver 2.21 working with Firefox 11

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using the 2.21 C# version of Webdriver via NuGet.  According to the release notes it should be working with Firefox 11. (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/CHANGELOG)

The code that was working with Webdriver 2.20 and Firefox 10, now breaks with Webdriver 2.21 and Firefox 11.

What is the fix for this?

The short error is:
Test 'RMIS_WebFrameworkTestsWebDriver.FrameworkTest_MyClass.MyTest' failed: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to start up socket within 45000

Comment: 2.20 was working Firefox 11 but Native Events weren't. Try 2.20 with Firefox 11 and see if it works.

Comment: Version 2.21 seems to be working when I downgrade to Firefox 10.  But NOT with Firefox 11.  Does anyone know if there are plans for the C# WebDriver to support Firefox 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my own (and rather dumb) problem.  In short, I was using NuGet to update the WebDriver code in my testing project.  What I didn't notice is that I had a previous version of the WebDriver DLL referenced separately (prior to using NuGet).  I did not notice that although NuGet installed WebDriver 'successfully' my code was still referencing the old dll.

I thought the new WebDriver code was not working with Firefox 11, but it was really my code was using an old version of WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Probably http://code.google.com/p/selenium/ is a better place to ask the Selenium developers directly. Personally I have also seen that FF11 has issues withe latest version of Selenium.